# Vue 3 composition API - ref doesn't work in npm package

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, ref, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have this very simple Vue 3 component. Everything works fine. `value` changes every 0.5s (console.log is being called) and the value changes in browser every 0.5s as well.

```js
<template>
  <pre>value: {{ value }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const value = ref(false)

    setInterval(() => {
      value.value = !value.value
      console.log('value changed to ', value.value)
    }, 500)

    return { value }
  }
})
</script>
```

And here is my problem ... If I create my own npm package, let's say `@my/package` with the following code:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

const value = ref(false)

setInterval(() => {
  value.value = !value.value
  console.log('value changed to ', value.value)
}, 500)

export { value }
```

and then I use my package in my Vue 3 component like this:

```js
<template>
  <pre>value: {{ value }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { value } from '@my/package'

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    return { value }
  }
})
</script>
```

then it doesn't work. Exactly said, the `console.log` logs the different values (`true` or `false`) every 0.5s but my browser still renders only the initial `false` value.

There are no errors in console. It just seems like my "reactivity" somehow magically refuse to work if the `ref()` is called outside of my Vue app.

This also doesn't work with `reactive()` and Vuex. I want to create a npm package that will expose some reactive references (created by `ref()`) and my Vue app will `import` these values. How to keep the reactivity in such a scenario? What am I missing here?

EDIT: I've just discovered that it DOES work correctly if I pass the `ref` from my Vue application to the npm package function. Example code:

```js
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import { createValue } from '@my/package'

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    // Notice Im passing the ref to the createValue function
    const value = createValue(ref)
    return { value }
  }
})
```

and my `@my/package` code:

```js
export function createValue (ref) {
  const value = ref(false)

  setInterval(() => {
    value.value = !value.value
    console.log('value changed to ', value.value)
  }, 500)

  return value
}
```

So it seems like the `ref` in my Vue app and the `ref` in my package aren't the same. But why?

EDIT 2: I saved my `ref` in the Vue app like `window.ref1 = ref` and then I saved my `ref` in the npm package like `window.ref2 = ref`. When I run `window.ref1 === window.ref2` it is false. So my `ref` inside Vue app is NOT the same like my `ref` in the npm package. I import both with the following code:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'
```

EDIT 3: So the real problem was that I had two separate Vue npm packages. One in `/node_modules/` and the second one in the `/node_modules/@my/package/node_modules`. Each Vue had it's own `ref` of course. I fixed this using peer dependency.

Comment: bit late. in my case wrapping the export seems to solve the issues. Instead of `export { value }`. I did `const myPlugin = { value }; ` `export { myPlugin }`

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution. The problem was that I linked the `@my/package` using the `$ yarn link` command so I had two copies of `vue`. So when I imported the `ref` within my Vue app, it was the different function than the `ref` imported within @my/package.

The easiest solution here is probably just to simply clone Vue repo and run `$ yarn link vue` in both the Vue app and the package.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to define that code inside composable function like :

```
import { ref,onMounted } from 'vue'

export default function useValue(){
     const value = ref(false)

     onMounted(()=>{
       setInterval(() => {
         value.value = !value.value
         console.log('value changed to ', value.value)
       }, 500)
     })

    return {value}
}
```

then use it like :

```
<template>
  <pre>value: {{ value }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import useValue from '@my/package'

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
  const { value} =useValue();

    return { value }
  }
})
</script>
```

**[EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/LYxGozg)**

Comment: Yes I know. I just tried to keep the code as simple as possible. But your example doesn't work for me :( It only works if I pass the `ref` to your `useValue()` function like this: `useValue(ref)`. I edited the original post.

Comment: it should work just import the ref like `import { ref } from 'vue'` no need to pass it as parameter

Comment: please check this example https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/LYxGozg

Comment: I checked the example. Thanks for help. But it didn't help me at all. I know your code works. It is basically the same like my first shown code. The problem is it doesn't work when I create my `ref` value in the npm package.

Comment: how do you build that npm module?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "build". But the problem is probably in my development process. I use yarn and I link that package. I run "$ yarn link" in the root folder of the package. Then I run "$ yarn link @my/package" in the root folder of my Vue app. Then I can write something like `import { ... } from '@my/package'` and it works, but the problem is that my npm package has it's own copy of Vue. So my `ref` in the npm is not the same like the `ref` in my Vue app. Im trying to figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one Vue application as an NPM package in another Vue application and you're getting issues where the reactivity of the application stops working, the suggestions mentioned by [@mspiderv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2987610/mspiderv) could help of course (they sent me in the right direction for sure).

What solved my issue completely in the end was to **add this to the webpack configuration of both Vue applications** (the main one and the one made available through an NPM package):

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue')
    }
}
```

Here's where I found this solution: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/1503

Just mentioning it here in case it helps someone else or provides a more ideal solution to the issue of [@mspiderv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2987610/mspiderv) in a better way.